# React website showing a blank white page and no content

Tags: scrapy-splash

My question is related to:
[Scrapy-splash not rendering dynamic content from a certain react-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483008/scrapy-splash-not-rendering-dynamic-content-from-a-certain-react-driven-site)

But disabling private mode did not fix the issue (passing `--disable-private-mode` as an argument to the Docker container).

I made a single page app using React and all it does is add an element to root:

```
function F(){
  class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        "Hello ",
        this.props.name
      );
    }
  }
  return(React.createElement(HelloMessage, { name: "Taylor" }));
}
```

But Splash only shows a blank white page!

I also made a single page website using Django and the HTML loads a script on head:

`<script src="/static/js/modify-the-dom.js"></script>`

And all the script does is to write something on the page after the content is loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.write('Modified the DOM!');
}
```

This change shows up on the browsers! But on on Splash, if I remove the `window.onload` and just write `document.write('Modified the DOM!');` it works fine! So the issue seems to be with `window.onload` even though I'm waiting long enough about 10 seconds on the LUA script.

So I was wondering how to fix that.
I also checked my Splash with this website and it seems JS is not enabled!
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled I wonder if there's an option I have not enabled?

One example of a client-rendering website that Splash does not crawl properly (same issues above) is https://www.digikala.com/ it only shows a blank white page with some HTML that needs to be populated with AJAX requests. Even https://web.archive.org/ does not crawl this website's pages properly and shows a blank page.

Thanks a lot!

**Update:**
The Splash script is:

```
function main(splash, args)
    splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(30)) -- Tried different timeouts.
    return {
      html = splash:html(),
      png = splash:png(),
      har = splash:har(),
    }
  end
```

I also tried setting these to no avail:

```
splash.plugins_enabled = true
splash.resource_timeout = 0
```

Comment: Please add the whole Splash code

Comment: @OfirD Added the Splash Lua script I was using.